# MySQL - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Please help
I'm pretty noob at this and I don't know how I should put the foreign key 
If anybody can help, I'll appreciate it!

```
mysql> 
    create table Evento
    (idEven int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    denominacion varchar(20),
    horaInicio time,
    idLugar int,
    cupo int,

    constraint PK_Evento primary key (idEven));

Query OK, 0 rows affected 

mysql> 
    create table Lugar
    (idLugar int NOT NULL,
    nombre varchar(20),
    direccion varchar(20),
    localidad varchar(20),

    constraint PK_Lugar primary key (idLugar),
    constraint FK_Lugar foreign key (idLugar) references Evento(idLugar));
```

`ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a foreign key from `event` to reference `place`.

That is, it looks like an "event" happens at one place, but a place can have many "events". To represent that in the "event" table, we reference the "place" that the event happens. You've already got the column there.

Just switch your thinking around... the foreign key is defined on the child table, and references the parent.  The `idLugar` column in the event table is a reference to a row in `Lugar`.

Just remove that second foreign key constraint from the `Lugar` table, and instead, add a constraint to the `Evento` table.

for example:

```
 ALTER TABLE `Evento` ADD
   CONSTRAINT FK_Evento_Lugar FOREIGN KEY (idLugar) REFERENCES Lugar(idLugar)
```

---

NOTE: Beware of *case-sensitivity* issues with table names. The pattern we have adopted to avoid problems is to lowercase all table names, and set `lower_case_table_names=1` in the my.cnf.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html